# std::chrono::time_point compiler error when converting from a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, most-vexing-parse

I have a variable of type `long long` that represents a time point in nanoseconds.

I'm trying to wrap it using std::chrono::time_point yet the compiler (VS 2017) is giving me troubles.

here is a code that compiles:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tpStart(std::chrono::nanoseconds(10ll));
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tpEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
double d =  std::chrono::duration<double>(tpEnd - tpStart).count();
```

Now if i switch the value `10ll` with a variable, the line that computes the duration fails to compile:

```
constexpr long long t = 10ll;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tpStart(std::chrono::nanoseconds(t));
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tpEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
double d =  std::chrono::duration<double>(tpEnd - tpStart).count();
```

Here is the error code:

*error C2679: binary '-': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)*

Any Idea why is this happening? how can I convert a variable of type long long to a std::chrono::time_point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR : It's a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) case

```
prog.cc:8:59: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tpStart(std::chrono::nanoseconds(t));
```

Fix with `{}` instead of `()`

```
constexpr long long t = 10ll;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tpStart{std::chrono::nanoseconds{t}};
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tpEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
double d =  std::chrono::duration<double>(tpEnd - tpStart).count();
```

---

**Why it's a most vexing parse?**

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> pStart  (std::chrono::nanoseconds(t));
//                  ^^^^ Type 1 ^^^^^              ^name^      ^^^^ Type 2 ^^^^
```

So we can reproduce with :

```
constexpr long long t = 10ll;
int fail (double (t) );
fail = 6; // compilation error here
```

Why ? Let's remove some noise :

```
int fail (double (t) );
//  <=> 
int fail (double t);
// <=>
int fail (double) ; // Most vexing parse.
```

We can fix it by switching to `{}`

```
int Ok {double {t} };
```